# Too many positional arguments, 0 expected, but 3 found

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a class notification to initialise my data, but when I call it in my future function it shows me an error.

```dart
Future <List<Notification>> _getNotification() async {
    var data = await http.get("$baseUrl/efficience001_webservice/notification.php");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<Notification> notifs = [];
    for (var u in jsonData){
      Notification notif = Notification(u["description"],u["nom_ligne"], u["created_at"]);
      notifs.add(notif);
    }
    print(notifs.length);
    return notifs;
}

class Notification {
  final String description;
  final String nom_ligne;
  final DateTime created_at;

  const Notification({this.description, this.nom_ligne, this.created_at});
}
```

```
error: Too many positional arguments , 0 expected, but 3 found.
```

Comment: Seems like you only want to convert JSON to object list! If yes then you are doing it in the wrong way! Check this documentation - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using [named parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters) for your `Notification` class but pass positional parameters.

You have two options to solve it:

- Use positional parameters for your class (remove curly braces). In order to do that, change your constructor in the `Notification` class to:

```dart
const Notification(this.description, this.nom_ligne, this.created_at);
```

- Supply named parameters when creating the object of your `Notification` class. In order to do this, change one line in your `for`-loop:

```dart
Notification notif =
  Notification(description: u["description"], nom_ligne: u["nom_ligne"], created_at: u["created_at"]);
```